# Wrong Issuer in ClaimsIdentity on Itfoxtec binding

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Our web api gets the SAML response from the Idp, and when we run the following code:

```
var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);
var httpRequest = Request.ToGenericHttpRequest();
binding.ReadSamlResponse(httpRequest, saml2AuthnResponse);
```

We can see that:
saml2AuthnResponse.Issuer is loaded with the correct issuer that we get in the response, for example ourdomain:saml2.
However, in the :
saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity.Claims[any index].Issuer is loaded with "LOCAL AUTHORITY".

We expect that all claims include Issuer same as in saml2AuthnResponse.Issuer.
Is it a bug, or we need to some changes in the code in order to align the Issuers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component is not setting the issuer or other properties on the `saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity.Claims`. You are welcome to do a pull request if you need the functionality added.